# Knockout Computed in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, typescript

#### Overview

I just want to write a Knockout Computed function in TypeScript as a property of a prototype. I know how to write a function as a property of a prototype when it's not a `ko.computed`. I know how to write a `ko.computed` as a property of just the object (but not the prototype), but I can't seem to find the right syntax for the intersection.

#### What I'd like (JS)

```
MyClass.prototype.myFunction = ko.computed(function(){

    // js goes here

});
```

#### What I have (TS)

```
myFunction():  any {

    ko.computed(function(){

        // code

     })

}
```

#### What my TS outputs (Not wanted)

```
MyClass.prototype.myFunction = function(){

    ko.computed(function(){

        // code

    })

});
```

#### Example of expression that TypeScript emits to prototype

*TS*

```
class MyClass {

    name: KnockoutObservable<string>;  

    editing: KnockoutObservable<boolean>;                    

    constructor(name: string) {

        this.name = ko.observable(fullName);

        this.editing = ko.observable(false);

    }

    edit(): void {

        this.editing(true);

    }

}
```

*JS*

```
var MyClass = (function () {
    function MyClass(name) {
        this.name = ko.observable(fullName);

        this.editing = ko.observable(false);
    }
    MyClass.prototype.edit = function () {
        this.editing(true);
    };
    return MyClass;
})();
```

I would find it truly puzzling if there wasn't a way to similarly write a ko.computed the way I described.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? If your prototype `computed` value depends on instance `observables`, you're going to retrigger computation across all instances of the class whenever an instance value changes in *any* instance, or possibly worse behavior

Comment: Good point; I do not want this on the prototype!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't syntax in TypeScript that emit an expression initialized on the prototype. You can do something like this instead:

```
class Foo {
    myFunction: ko.computed<string>;
}
Foo.prototype.myFunction = function() {
    return 'hello' + 'world';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What you could do is use the observable's `owner` property to provide the scope to be used in the computed:

```
class MyViewModel {
    myFunction = () => ko.computed({
        owner: this,
        read: function() {
            // code
        }
    })
}
```

This gives you the following output:

```
var MyViewModel = (function () {
    function MyViewModel() {
        var _this = this;
        this.myFunction = function () {
            return ko.computed({
                owner: _this,
                read: function () {
                    // code
                }
            });
        };
    }
    return MyViewModel;
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```ts
myFunction: KnockoutComputed<string> = ko.computed(() => {
    // return any string value
 });
```